# Is this database correctly structured?

Tags: mysql, database-design, sqlite, python, application-design

I am in the process of converting a bus timetable to a database structure. I am building a free mobile app for a specific itinerary in my country that will:

- let users know when their next bus is due to arrive,
- tell them how long it will take to arrive at their destination,
- alert them x minutes before their planned trip, etc...

The app will be implemented in Python with Kivy, and a SQLite database. It will be able to run offline.

This is the original timetable:

[image: Original]

And this is what I have come up with...

[image]

Code:

```
Table stop as S {
  stop_id int [pk, increment] // auto-increment
  name varchar
  coordinates_id int [ref: - C.coordinates_id]
}

Table coordinates as C {
  coordinates_id int
  latitude float
  longitude float
}

Table user as U {
  user_id int [pk, increment]
  name varchar
  tax_number int
  buspass_id int [ref: - B.buspass_id]
}

Table buspass as B {
  buspass_id int
  start_stop int [ref: - S.stop_id]
  end_stop int [ref: - S.stop_id]
  validity datetime
}

Table route as R {
  route_id int [pk, increment]
  disabled boolean
  route_frequency enum
  route_direction enum
  route_type enum
 }

Table timetable as TT {
  timetable_id int [pk, increment]
  route_id int [ref: > R.route_id] 
  stop_id int [ref: > S.stop_id]
  time timestamp
}

//----------------------------------------------//
Enum route_direction {
  coimbra_serpins
  serpins_coimbra
}

Enum route_frequency {
  daily
  not_saturday
  wednesday
  not_sunday_or_holidays
  not_weekend_or_holidays
  saturday
  school [note: "not weekends, holidays or July and August"]
  not_july_or_august
}

Enum route_type {
  direct_miranda
  direct_lousa
  semidirect_miranda_lousa
  semidirect_lousa_serpins
}
```

I will need to do a bunch of queries such as:

- Find the next departure based on the current time and departure location, and arrival location and arrival time.
- List all stops of the ideal route, with arrival times for each.
- Know if bus pass is almost out of data, i.e. when it was purchased.

I would like to know if this structure seems appropriate for my end goal.

Comment: What will the lat/lng be used for?  Is the "frequency" constant?  Or does it change for nights, weekends, holidays?  Try to write the `SELECTs` that you will need.

Comment: Lat long is for storing geolocation of bus stops, so I can integrate Google Maps API later on. Frequency is constant.

Comment: Time of timetable is a timestamp.  A timestamp contains a date.  Do you plan to store routes for a number of months or years ahead?  Over here, routes depend on the day of the week, eg. mon- to friday, saturday, sundays and holidays, not on the exact date.  They'd have to renew the charts in the bus-stops.  Not that they couldn't do that, they change the ads every so often.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please don't use images here for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Please put in the referential constraints - also, please show us what you have attempted yourself - help us  to help you.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW, he put the design in text and he didn't ask for us to write his queries.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't design a solution for Miranda and Lousa, but one for Portugal in its entirety.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - comment revised - thanks for pointing out my error!

Comment: @Steffan - you can go to dbfiddle.uk to construct a schema with actual DRI (Declarative Referential Integrity) constraints.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW the comment about the pictures is often to the point.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille thank you for pointing out the timestamp. It will only store HH:MM of the stop, not date. Is this the wrong type? Maybe I should store as string and convert to time format in python instead?

Comment: @Steffan https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html  time with/without timezone?

Comment: Are some of your routes circular, or do they all go from A to B and return the same way?

Comment: Shouldn't the buspass validity be a range date from - date to?  Or are all valid for the same time?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes, time without timezone, I will use that type thanks. There are no circular routes, just linear, which are defined by route_direction (Coimbra to Serpins, or Serpins to Coimbra). I could of made it a Boolean but it seems more clear as enum. Busspass validity is always the first day of next month after purchase, there is no range.

Comment: If only Sugarmountain had limited the use of Faecesbook to Harvard, this would have been a better world.  Are you sure you'll get rich building an app that can only be used for bus travellers between two specific cities?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille no, the app is completely free.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` vs `DATETIME` -- Beware of daylight savings time.

Comment: Are there extra busses when there is some big event?

Comment: 1:1 relationships are frowned upon.  It seems like lat/lng can be included in table S, thereby eliminating table C.

Comment: @RickJames I think once a year there are extra busses for a week, why do you ask? I can just add another route frequency entry for those if that is the case , right? Yes, I noticed that about the coordinates, thanks.